# Splunkorwarder using ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, debian, splunk

I would like to monitor multiple logs on the universal forwarder. How can i do this? Also when I set forward-server am running out in error. with Enable boot-start somehow i have to accept license manually to finish up the installation. Any suggestions, please?

```
- name: connect forward server to Splunk server
  command: "{{ splunkbin }} add forward-server {{ item }} -auth {{ splunkcreds }}"
  with_items: "{{ splunkserver }}"
  when: splunkserver is defined
  notify: restart_splunk

- name: Enable Boot Start
  command: "{{ splunkbin }} enable boot-start"

- name: add temporary monitor to create directory
  command: "{{ splunkbin }} add monitor /etc/hosts -auth {{ splunkcreds }}"
  notify: restart_splunk
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following to accept the license without prompting

```
- name: Enable Boot Start
  command: "{{ splunkbin }} enable boot-start --accept-license"
```

Comment: It really didnot help it get stuck at the task. when i run manually it pop ups with more option and then after scrolling many pages i have to accept the license.

Comment: This is from the official ansible playbook that Splunk uses, https://github.com/splunk/splunk-ansible